# How can we create/add users in user pool using cloud formation in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried by reading documentation, it gives me validation errors.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html?icmpid=docs_cfn_console_designer

Comment: What validation errors do you get?  The more information you give in your question, the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: it is showing that [member must satisfy enum value set] while giving alias attributes (username, contact_no, email).